# How to extract all the text under a particular header from an html file

Tags: javascript, html, xmllint

I am trying to extract all the text under a particular Heading from an html file.
I want to use the xmllint utility for the same.
I am working in a Linux Environment.

Here is the html file: https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.6#Block

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="Linux, kernel, operating system, changes, changelog, file system, Linus Torvalds, open source, device drivers">
<meta name="description" content="Summary of the changes and new features merged in the Linux kernel during the 3.6 development cycle">
<meta name="robots" content="index,nofollow">

<title>Linux_3.6 - Linux Kernel Newbies</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/moin_static199/common/js/common.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var search_hint = "Search";
.............
.............
<h1 id="Block">5. Block</h1>
<span class="anchor" id="line-118"></span><ul><li><p class="line862">Add a new operation code (BLKPG_RESIZE_PARTITION) to the BLKPG ioctl that allows altering the size of an existing partition, even if it is currently in use <a class="http" href="http://git.kernel.org/linus/c83f6bf98dc1f1a194118b3830706cebbebda8c4">(commit)</a> <span class="anchor" id="line-119"></span></li><li><p class="line862">Device mapper RAID: Add support for MD RAID10 <a class="http" href="http://git.kernel.org/linus/63f33b8dda88923487004b20fba825486d009e7b">(commit)</a> <span class="anchor" id="line-120"></span></li><li><p class="line862">Device mapper thin: add read-only and fail I/O modes <a class="http" href="http://git.kernel.org/linus/e49e582965b3694f07a106adc83ddb44aa4f0890">(commit)</a> <span class="anchor" id="line-121"></span></li><li><p class="line862">Device mapper: remove persistent data debug space map checker <a class="http" href="http://git.kernel.org/linus/3caf6d73d4dc163b2d135e0b52b052a2b63e5216">(commit)</a> <span class="anchor" id="line-122"></span></li><li><p class="line862">md/raid1: prevent merging too large request <a class="http" href="http://git.kernel.org/linus/12cee5a8a29e7263e39953f1d941f723c617ca5f">(commit)</a> <span class="anchor" id="line-123"></span><span class="anchor" id="line-124"></span></li></ul><p class="line867">
.............
.............
        },
        clickWrapper: function () {
          if ( ($(this).attr('href') === location.hash)
               || !('onhashchange' in window.document.body) ) {
            setTimeout(function () { $(window).trigger("hashchange"); }, 1);
          }
        },
      };
      $('#pagebox a[href^="#"]:not([href="#"])').on("click", mdAnchorFix.clickWrapper);
      $(window).on("hashchange", mdAnchorFix.jump);
      if (location.hash) setTimeout(function () { mdAnchorFix.jump(); }, 100);
    }(jQuery);
  </script>

  <!-- End of JavaScript -->
</body>
</html>
```

I want the following output:

```
5. Block

    Add a new operation code (BLKPG_RESIZE_PARTITION) to the BLKPG ioctl that allows altering the size of an existing partition, even if it is currently in use (commit)

    Device mapper RAID: Add support for MD RAID10 (commit)

    Device mapper thin: add read-only and fail I/O modes (commit)

    Device mapper: remove persistent data debug space map checker (commit)

    md/raid1: prevent merging too large request (commit)
```

Basically, I want to create a script which extracts the description of the changes to the Block Layer in different Kernel versions, from the Kernel Newbies website.

URL for reference:
https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.6#Block

Comment: Just to clarify: is your desired output `5. Block`?

Comment: @JackFleeting question updated

Comment: The content of the link are different from the html you posted in the question.

Comment: sorry, updated the link in the question.

Comment: It's possible to get your target info from that link, but probably not with xmllint, because xmllint expects xml, that page is in html and xmllint views that as invalid xml. The link can be parsed with xidel, if available to you, using an xpath expression. Note that the output will include your target info, but not in the format you indicated in the question; you will have to process it with your other tools. If all this works for you, I can post an answer.

Comment: Yes, this works for me as well. Please post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, you can get most of the way there using xidel instead of xmllint. So try this:

```
 xidel https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.6 --extract '//h1[@id="Block"]//following-sibling::ul[1]//p/text()'
```